# Show data for two different dates in columns

Tags: sql, google-analytics, bigdata, google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery I want to show the data for two different dates side by side. I want to show the data for today, and then the data for seven days ago for comparison. My FROM clause selects a range of tables, each table corresponds to a date.

```
SELECT
  DATE(TIMESTAMP(INTEGER(visitStartTime*1000000))) AS GMT_Date,
  DAYOFWEEK(TIMESTAMP(INTEGER(visitStartTime*1000000))) AS GMT_Weekday,
  IF(hits.customDimensions.index=15, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL) AS apikey,
  hits.eventInfo.eventCategory AS event_category,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS visit_count,


  DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(INTEGER(visitStartTime*1000000)),-7,"DAY")) AS test,
 // HERE I need to show SUM(totals.visits) but for the date of 'test' above

FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([100610078.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('20150529'),TIMESTAMP('20150711')))
WHERE
  IF(hits.customDimensions.index=15, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  GMT_Date,
  GMT_Weekday,
  event_category,
  test,
  apikey
ORDER BY
  GMT_Date DESC,
  visit_count DESC
LIMIT
  30
```

After 'test', I want to show the sum of the visits for the date of test. How would I go about this? I don't see anything similar to this on the BigQuery Syntax page.

Here's an image of what it's currently returning: http://prntscr.com/7s8w58

After the 'test' column, I want a column like previous_week_visits that has the same data as the visit_count but for the date of test.

Comment: you'll need to run subqueries. Using subqueries you will be able to separate your visits per day. Then you do a select on that, aggregating per day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to use window functions. You can map DATE into consequtive INTEGER by using DATEDIFF with fixed base, and then use LAG function to look up values, the following query shows an example for this approach:

```
select 
  d,
  value,
  lag(d, 3) over (order by diff) prev_d,
  lag(value, 3) over (order by diff) prev_value
from (
select d, datediff(d, date('1970-01-01')) diff, value from
(select date('2012-01-01') d, 'a' value),
(select date('2012-01-02') d, 'b' value),
(select date('2012-01-03') d, 'c' value),
(select date('2012-01-04') d, 'd' value),
(select date('2012-01-05') d, 'e' value),
(select date('2012-01-06') d, 'f' value),
(select date('2012-01-07') d, 'g' value),
(select date('2012-01-08') d, 'h' value),
(select date('2012-01-09') d, 'i' value),
(select date('2012-01-10') d, 'j' value)
)
```

It results in:

```
Row d           value   prev_d      prev_value   
1   2012-01-01  a       null        null     
2   2012-01-02  b       null        null     
3   2012-01-03  c       null        null     
4   2012-01-04  d       2012-01-01  a    
5   2012-01-05  e       2012-01-02  b    
6   2012-01-06  f       2012-01-03  c    
7   2012-01-07  g       2012-01-04  d    
8   2012-01-08  h       2012-01-05  e    
9   2012-01-09  i       2012-01-06  f    
10  2012-01-10  j       2012-01-07  g
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is definitely in the direction I need. Why is '1970-01-01' selected? And would I still be able to use this FROM table_date_range?

Comment: You can select any constant date, it is only used to convert timestamp into consequtive integer number. And you should be able to use table_date_range functions together with window functions.

Comment: What if I wanted to add different data granularities, so that there was more than one row per date? The lag function subtracts rows, not dates; is there a way to subtract dates and show the value?

Comment: If you will use RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING window - then LAG should subtract days, not rows, i.e. you can have same day multiple times and LAG(d, 3) will go back as far as needed